# Stopping slidedown submenu from sliding up when hovering over submenu

Tags: jquery, navigation, slidedown, slideup

I have the following script which handles the sliding down a submenu:

```
$('#nav li #bottom').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('#nav li').find('#sub_nav').slideDown("slow");
},
function() {
    $(this).closest('#nav li').find('#sub_nav').slideUp("slow");
});
```

The script is written in this way so that the slidedown will only be triggered when the user hovers over one of the divs within the nav list items, i.e. #bottom.

The trouble I am having is that though the slide down works fine, the menu slides up when the user hovers over the submenu and, of course, I don't want the submenu to slide up until the mouse/cursor leaves `#nav li #bottom` or `#sub_nav`.

I have created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickharambee/uVbJp/) so that you can see the menu in action.

**SCREENSHOT OF STRUCTURE OF NAV ITEM**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap the `#sub_nav` by `div#wrapper`, this way `sub_menu` is a part of bottom:

```
<div id="bottom">
    <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
    <ul id="sub_nav">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

also you can use `stop()` method:

```
$('#nav li #bottom').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('#sub_nav').stop().slideDown("slow");
},
function() {
    $(this).find('#sub_nav').stop().slideUp("slow");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uVbJp/3/)

Comment: Thanks, that does answer my question, so I will of course mark it as such. Unfortunately I forgot some crucial information.  The site I would like to use the script on is a Wordpress site and I am not sure how to customise the theme so that the submenu ul is created within the #bottom div.  Hence my using .closest('nav li') in the above script.  Is there a way of adapting the script to work with a ul that is outside of the #bottom div?  I have included a screenshot of the structure of the nav item generated at the end of my original answer.

Comment: @Nick you are welcome, you can try this script, which is based in original html structure http://jsfiddle.net/uVbJp/4/

Comment: Thanks again.  I have implemented your suggestion, but things are still not working out as I hoped.  You can see the page that I am trying to get it working on [here](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk).  The second navigation item 'News' has a submenu, and I have included your script (amended for the correct classes) in other.js (lines 73-85). As you can see the submenu is still appearing when the user hovers over .top_nav, and also when the cursor moves out of the sub-menu div the script no longer works. Would you be able to have a look at this?

Comment: I have marked the question as answered, as it does answer the original question.  If you have any ideas as to how to get this working with my particular markup then I'd be glad to hear of it.  If I find anything else out I'll report back